# How to do Localization - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, localization, locale

I want to be able to test my cakephp web page using the localization features.

I use the translate function __() and I also use the date and time function: `toLocaleString()`

I wanted to know how can I test the translation and localization in a simple way.

I know that `toLocaleString()` will output the date and time in the local format.

I tried using the following code in my controller's beforeFilter():

```
$this->Session->write('Config.langauge', 'ger');
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
```

The above two lines of code didn't work.
This did not work either:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de', 'ge');
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.
I also installed a spanish, french and german language pack.

In the cakephp debug toolkit, it shows that the language has changed, but the date and time string do not change at all.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

As for testing, the date and time should work once the locale is set, but for the translate functions, how do I test those?
I looked into the cakephp documentation, but it says to use the i18n console commang.
I tried running the command to extract pot files and I chose my source and output directory, but nothing showed up in the directory when it was done.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below url

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Or try this:

```
//Internationalizing Your Application

<h2><?php echo __('Posts'); ?></h2>

The default domain is ‘default’, therefore your locale folder would look something like this:

/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (English)
/app/Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)
/app/Locale/por/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (Portuguese)


<?php
// App Controller Code.
public function beforeFilter() {
    $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    if ($locale && file_exists(VIEWS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath)) {
        // e.g. use /app/View/fre/Pages/tos.ctp instead of /app/View/Pages/tos.ctp
        $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
    }
}


or:


<?php
// View code
echo $this->element(Configure::read('Config.language') . '/tos');




//Localization in CakePHP

<?php
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
?>

<?php
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');
?>


<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    }
}
?>


///Translating model validation errors

<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validationDomain = 'validation';

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
                'length' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 2, 10),
                'message' => 'Username should be between %d and %d characters'
            )
        )
    )
}
?>

//Which will do the following internal call:

<?php
__d('validation', 'Username should be between %d and %d characters', array(2, 10));
```